# Macbook python3 alias is ephemere

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

When I change the alias for python using `alias python='python3'` in terminal, the python version will be changed to python3. But, when I close Atom and come back to the app later, it has gone back to python2. Can someone explain this please?

Comment: You need to save the alias in your `.bashrc` so it will be set every time you start a terminal.

Comment: if you have the new MacOS then you migrated to `zsh` so you need to define the alias in **.zhrc**

Comment: @fatmink : I do not understand the question. How is this related to the `atom` editor? How, and where exactly do you set the alias? You have a bash shell open in a terminal, define the alias, then you start atom, and after ending atom, the alias in the very same shell you have defined it, is gone???

Answer (score 1):

Your alias is only available in the current shell , put the alias in `~/.bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc`